# Delete a cell row in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

Want to delete a row when you swipe with your finger on the cell.

I got this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Delete");
}
```

After running the Delete button appears but when I press on it nothing happens. What do I need to insert in to the brackets?

And my .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"U selected %@", str);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.dataSourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//or something similar to this based on your data source array structure
        //remove the corresponding object from your data source array before this or else you will get a crash
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.array = @[@"test",@"test"];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:nil action:@selector(updateArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect something to happen when you do nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//or something similar to this based on your data source array structure
//remove the corresponding object from your data source array before this or else you will get a crash
     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: did not you forget to remove item at appropriate indexPath from dataSource?

Comment: @Vladimir, Thanks. I was typing that comment there when you posted the comment. Check it now.

Comment: @user1883396 You have to remove that index from the array populating your table too.

Comment: @user1883396, you need to remove it from the array. Or else you will get a crash as `'NSInternalInconsistencyException',  
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows....`

Comment: @ACB got a error that dataSourceArray is not found on object of type TableViewController

Comment: @user1883396, That is because your data source array name is `array`. So you should make that line as `self.array` instead of `self.dataSourceArray`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok after that i got this error: "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'"

Comment: @user1883396: That means you're using an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray. If you want to be able to add and delete items, you need to use an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @user1883396, Declare your `NSArray *array;` as a mutable array. So it will be like, `NSMutableArray *array;` Change `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`, wherever you are using `NSArray` related to `array` param.

Comment: Ok got that, and the error is away but got another warning that my self.array = @[@"test",@"test"];  = Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'

Comment: @user1883396, Change that to `self.array = (NSMutableArray *)@[@"test",@"test"];` or `self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test",@"test", nil];`

Comment: The "Was this post useful to you?" ? I clicked Yes